# What is priority of parameters passed to maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I see that a parameter can be configured in `pom.xml` or passed in the CLI such as `-Dxxxxx=...`

My question is if the same parameter is both configured in file `pom.xml` and passed in the CLI, which will be used by the maven plugin? Is there any document about this priority?

Mostly I believe CLI will override, but this real case shows the opposite.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rspec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta</version>
    <configuration>
        <launchDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</launchDirectory>
        <summaryReport>${project.build.directory}/test-Ruby.xml</summaryReport>
        <specSourceDirectory>./new_test</specSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I ran

```
mvn test -DspecSourceDirectory=./spec
```

The plugin still picked the `specSourceDirectory` in the `pom.xml` which is `./new_test`

I'm using maven 3.0.5, java 7, jruby 1.7.5

---

Got it resolved: it should be a property instead of a hardcode

```
<specSourceDirectory>${specSourceDirectory}</specSourceDirectory>
```

Comment: The command line param overrides, IIRC. Seems easy enough to test that assumption.

Comment: If pom parameters overrode CLI parameters, then it markedly diminishes the usefulness of the CLI parameters.

Comment: @DaveNewton: is it a convention or enforced by maven code?

Comment: ... By Maven code, how else would it be able to take priority?

Comment: I don't think so, I will update the question to show my case

Comment: That's not a property you're trying to replace-you have no property, the path is hard-coded.

Comment: @DaveNewton when I removed out the specSourceDirectory in pom.xml, which will use default value "spec", then I passed -DspecSourceDirectory=./new_test in CLI, it can get the latter

Comment: Neat. You hard-coded the path. Properties replace *properties*, not arbitrary element values. See `${project.build.directory}`? That's a replaceable property, used correctly. See `./new_test`? Not a property, a hard-coded value.

Comment: @DaveNewton: hey, I got you. You mean a property is defined in pom.xml, and passing that property to a parameter. If I pass that property in CLI with a new value, it will override?

Comment: ... If you put the tag and hard code a value, you're setting its value. I don't know what else to tell you. If you'd used a property instead of hardcoding you'd get what you expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80479/discussion-between-truong-ha-and-dave-newton).

Answer (score 1):

One thing is a plugin's configuration parameter and the other thing is Maven's invocation property (user property). For example, look at [Surefire's skip configuration parameter](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip). There is a `skip` parameter that can be set up by `maven.test.skip` property. In general these 2 names are independent, so can be either different or the same.

In your case, `<specSourceDirectory>${specSourceDirectory}</specSourceDirectory>` will be such a latter scenario and will work as you expect.